Python pcolormesh heatmap not visible on plot (for monthly tropical cyclone track climatology in the Southern Pacific)
I am trying to make Python plots of the monthly tropical cyclone (TC) track climatology in the Southern Pacific basin. But, the gridded heatmap of the frequency of TC track passage per grid that I was supposed to make using pcolormesh does not appear on the plot, resulting in a map with plain white background.
Apparently, this problem is related to the issue of dealing with data and maps that cross the antimeridian (180°), of which I am not quite familiar with the needed workaround. I have done the same plots without any problems in other regions (e.g. Western North Pacific, Indian Ocean, North Atlantic, Eastern North Pacific) since none of these regions cross the antimeridian. I am using data from the IBTrACS (International Best Track Archive for Climate Stewardship) dataset.
This is what I managed to make so far:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colorbar import ColorbarBase
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

# Extracting TC best track data from the IBTrACS CSV files
all_TC_tracks = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Brian/Desktop/ibtracs.SP.list.v04r00.csv',
                      usecols=['SID', 'ISO_TIME', 'LAT', 'LON'])

# Converting the string times into datetime type
all_TC_tracks['ISO_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(all_TC_tracks['ISO_TIME'])

# Extracting the month value from the datetimes
all_TC_tracks['MONTH'] = all_TC_tracks['ISO_TIME'].dt.month

# Converting the longitude values from [-180, 180] notation to [0, 360] notation
all_TC_tracks['LON'] = np.where(all_TC_tracks['LON'] < 0, all_TC_tracks['LON'] + 360, all_TC_tracks['LON'])
# This is necessary since the Southern Pacific basin crosses the antimeridian (180°).

# Determining the month of occurence of each TC
# by identifying the mode of all month values per TC best track
most_frequent_month = all_TC_tracks.groupby('SID')['MONTH'].agg(lambda x: mode(x)[0])

most_frequent_month = most_frequent_month.map({
1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May',
6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October',
11: 'November', 12: 'December'})

all_TC_tracks = all_TC_tracks.merge(
most_frequent_month, how='left', on='SID').rename(
columns={'MONTH_y': 'MOST_FREQUENT_MONTH'})

all_TC_tracks.drop(columns=['ISO_TIME','MONTH_x'], inplace=True)
all_TC_tracks.rename(columns={'MOST_FREQUENT_MONTH': 'MONTH'}, inplace=True)

def plot_monthly_tracks(month):
    # Filter the DataFrame to only include rows for a specific month
    monthly_tracks = all_TC_tracks[all_TC_tracks['MONTH'] == month]

    # Group the DataFrame by 'SID'
    grouped = monthly_tracks.groupby('SID')
    
    # Initialize an empty list to store the dictionaries
    monthly_TCs = []
    
    # Iterate over the grouped DataFrame
    for name, group in grouped:
        # Create a dictionary where the key is the SID and the value is a list of lat-lon tuples
        tc_dict = {name: list(zip(group['LAT'], group['LON']))}
        # Append the dictionary to the list
        monthly_TCs.append(tc_dict)
    
    # Create a 2D array for the histogram
    hist = np.zeros((75, 95)) #70S-5N, 155E-110W
    print(hist)
    
    # Iterate over the tropical cyclones
    for tc in monthly_TCs:
        for sid, locations in tc.items():
            # Create a set to store the grid boxes that this tropical cyclone passes through
            visited_boxes = set()
            for lat, lon in locations:
                # Calculate the indices of the grid box that this location falls into
                lat_index = int(lat - (-70))
                lon_index = int(lon - 155)
                # Check if the indices are within the expected range
                if 0 <= lat_index < 75 and 0 <= lon_index < 95:
                    # Add the grid box to the set of visited boxes
                    visited_boxes.add((lat_index, lon_index))
            # Increment the count in the histogram for each visited box
            for lat_index, lon_index in visited_boxes:
                hist[lat_index, lon_index] += 1
                # print(hist[lat_index, lon_index])
    
    # Define the edges of the bins for the histogram
    xedges = np.arange(155, 251, 1)  # 95 elements
    yedges = np.arange(-70, 6, 1)  # 75 elements
    
    print(xedges)
    print(yedges)
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25., 25.), dpi=250)
    revised_projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=revised_projection)
    ax.set_extent([155, 250, -70, 5], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    gridlines = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, xlocs=np.arange(-180, 181, 5), ylocs=np.arange(-90, 91, 5), color='gray', linestyle='--')
    xticks = np.arange(155, 251, 5)
    yticks = np.arange(-70, 6, 5)
    ax.set_xticks(xticks, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_yticks(yticks, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(LONGITUDE_FORMATTER)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LATITUDE_FORMATTER)
    
    ax.coastlines('10m', edgecolor='black', linewidth=2.5)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, edgecolor='black', linewidth=2.5)
    
    # Plot the histogram as a heatmap on the geographical map
    cax = ax.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, hist, vmin=0, vmax=50, cmap='PuRd', shading='auto')
    print(cax)
    
    # Add a colorbar
    cax = fig.add_axes([0.92, 0.25, 0.02, 0.5])
    norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=50)
    colorbar = ColorbarBase(cax, cmap='PuRd', norm=norm, extend='max', ticks=np.arange(0, 51, 2))
    colorbar.set_label('Frequency of tropical cyclone passage', size=25)
    cax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
    
    # Iterate over the tropical cyclones
    for tc in monthly_TCs:
        for sid, locations in tc.items():
            # Unzip the list of lat-lon tuples into two separate lists
            lats, lons = zip(*locations)
            # Plot the track of the tropical cyclone
            ax.plot(lons, lats, color='black', linewidth=0.2, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    # Add a title and subtitle
    fig.suptitle('IBTrACS | Monthly climatology of Southern Pacific tropical cyclone tracks (1848–2023)', fontsize=29, y=0.851)
    ax.set_title(month.upper(), fontsize=40, pad=20)
    
    plt.show()
    
    return hist

# List of months

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

# Generate a plot for each month

for month in months:
    hist = plot_monthly_tracks(month)
    # break

# End of program

I tried examining the contents of the 2D histogram in the 'hist' variable, thinking that it is empty. But, the Variable Explorer in Spyder indicates that it is not empty.
Contents of the 'hist' variable
I also tried printing the contents of the variables 'xedges' and 'yedges', but the console shows that they contain the expected values for the cell boundaries of each "box" in the histogram.
Also, the longitude labels are rendered incorrectly: lines of longitude to the west of the antimeridian (within Eastern Hemisphere) are labelled as °W, while the lines of longitude to the east of the antimeridian (within Western Hemisphere) are labelled as °E. This is after I attempted to convert the longitude values from [-180, 180] notation to [0, 360] notation, and centered the projection over the antimeridian (since not doing so would result in a map that shows the whole Southern Hemisphere from -180 to 180 degrees).
Resulting plot
What is the cause of this issue? And how exactly do I fix this? Or is there any better workaround in making these kinds of plots in Python?
Your responses and recommendations on this matter are highly appreciated. Thank you!

I have not tried, but I think you just need the transform keyword in your call to pcolormesh, the same as you do in plot.

It's a problem of dealing with the anti-meridian. Many libraries assume longitudes between -180 and 180 degrees. In your case, since you are working with longitudes in the range [0, 360] you need to ensure that your data handles the anti-meridian crossing correctly. Also the labels need to be adjusted to reflect the correct notation.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colorbar import ColorbarBase
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

dtypes = {
    'SID': str,
    'ISO_TIME': str,
    'LAT': str,
    'LON': str
}

all_TC_tracks = pd.read_csv(
    r"C:\Users\serge.degossondevare\Downloads\ibtracs.SP.list.v04r00.csv",
    usecols=['SID', 'ISO_TIME', 'LAT', 'LON'],
    dtype=dtypes,
    low_memory=False
)

all_TC_tracks['ISO_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(all_TC_tracks['ISO_TIME'], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

all_TC_tracks = all_TC_tracks.dropna(subset=['ISO_TIME'])

all_TC_tracks['MONTH'] = all_TC_tracks['ISO_TIME'].dt.month

all_TC_tracks['LAT'] = pd.to_numeric(all_TC_tracks['LAT'], errors='coerce')
all_TC_tracks['LON'] = pd.to_numeric(all_TC_tracks['LON'], errors='coerce')

all_TC_tracks = all_TC_tracks.dropna(subset=['LAT', 'LON'])

all_TC_tracks['LON'] = np.where(all_TC_tracks['LON'] < 0, all_TC_tracks['LON'] + 360, all_TC_tracks['LON'])

most_frequent_month = all_TC_tracks.groupby('SID')['MONTH'].agg(lambda x: mode(x)[0])

most_frequent_month = most_frequent_month.map({
    1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May',
    6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October',
    11: 'November', 12: 'December'})

all_TC_tracks = all_TC_tracks.merge(
    most_frequent_month, how='left', on='SID').rename(
    columns={'MONTH_y': 'MOST_FREQUENT_MONTH'})

all_TC_tracks.drop(columns=['ISO_TIME', 'MONTH_x'], inplace=True)
all_TC_tracks.rename(columns={'MOST_FREQUENT_MONTH': 'MONTH'}, inplace=True)

def plot_monthly_tracks(month):
    monthly_tracks = all_TC_tracks[all_TC_tracks['MONTH'] == month]

    grouped = monthly_tracks.groupby('SID')
    
    monthly_TCs = []
    
    for name, group in grouped:
        tc_dict = {name: list(zip(group['LAT'], group['LON']))}
        monthly_TCs.append(tc_dict)
    
    hist = np.zeros((75, 95))  
    print(hist)
    
    for tc in monthly_TCs:
        for sid, locations in tc.items():
            visited_boxes = set()
            for lat, lon in locations:
                lat_index = int(lat - (-70))
                lon_index = int(lon - 155)
                if 0 <= lat_index < 75 and 0 <= lon_index < 95:
                    visited_boxes.add((lat_index, lon_index))
            for lat_index, lon_index in visited_boxes:
                hist[lat_index, lon_index] += 1
    
    xedges = np.arange(155, 251, 1) 
    yedges = np.arange(-70, 6, 1)  
    
    print(xedges)
    print(yedges)
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25., 25.), dpi=250)
    revised_projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=revised_projection)
    ax.set_extent([155, 250, -70, 5], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    gridlines = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, xlocs=np.arange(-180, 181, 5), ylocs=np.arange(-90, 91, 5), color='gray', linestyle='--')
    xticks = np.arange(155, 251, 5)
    yticks = np.arange(-70, 6, 5)
    ax.set_xticks(xticks, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_yticks(yticks, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(LONGITUDE_FORMATTER)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LATITUDE_FORMATTER)
    
    ax.coastlines('10m', edgecolor='black', linewidth=2.5)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, edgecolor='black', linewidth=2.5)
    
    cax = ax.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, hist, vmin=0, vmax=50, cmap='PuRd', shading='auto', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    print(cax)
    
    cax = fig.add_axes([0.92, 0.25, 0.02, 0.5])
    norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=50)
    colorbar = ColorbarBase(cax, cmap='PuRd', norm=norm, extend='max', ticks=np.arange(0, 51, 2))
    colorbar.set_label('Frequency of tropical cyclone passage', size=25)
    cax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
    
    for tc in monthly_TCs:
        for sid, locations in tc.items():
            lats, lons = zip(*locations)
            ax.plot(lons, lats, color='black', linewidth=0.2, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    fig.suptitle('IBTrACS | Monthly climatology of Southern Pacific tropical cyclone tracks (1848–2023)', fontsize=29, y=0.851)
    ax.set_title(month.upper(), fontsize=40, pad=20)
    
    plt.show()
    
    return hist

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

for month in months:
    hist = plot_monthly_tracks(month)

which gives you for one month,  (I took only parts of the plot as there is a limit of 2MB for images on SO).

